# On the conditions of Arzela Ascoli theorem

Tags: arzela-ascoli

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $F\subseteq C(X;\mathbb{R})$ be a family of functions. Then
according to Arzela Ascoli $F$ is compact if and only if $F$ is equicontinuous at any point $t$ and $F$ is uniformly bounded.

But I think uniform boundedness is implied already by equicontinuity.

So equicontinuity should be equivalent to compactness here, no?

Because of
$\sup\limits_{f\in F}|f(x)-f(y)|\rightarrow 0$ $(x\rightarrow y)$

one has

$\left|\sup\limits_{f\in F}|f(x)|-\sup\limits_{f\in F}|f(y)|\right|\rightarrow 0$ $(x\rightarrow y)$

So $\sup\limits_{f\in F}|f(x)|$ is continuous and since $X$ is compact one has

$\sup\limits_{x\in X}\sup\limits_{f\in F}|f(x)|<+\infty$

but $\sup\limits_{x\in X}\sup\limits_{f\in F}|f(x)|=\sup\limits_{f\in F}\sup\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)|$

so $f$ is uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection of constant functions $f_n(x) = n$ for all $x$ is equicontinuous but not uniformly bounded.

Comment: I edited my post and why I thought it is uniformly bounded. Where is the mistake?

Comment: It is more instructive to figure it out yourself, by using the counterexample and tracing your attempt.

Comment: I see thee inverse triangle inequality is only applicable if $\sup\limits_f |f(x)|$ is finite.

Comment: But that would mean $\sup\limits_f |f(x)|<+\infty$ is enough instead of uniform boundedness right (at any $x$)?